# How do I get WebStorm to recognize the React variable name?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

React is included in my project, but WebStorm is not recognizing the variable name `React` when I'm using it in code (gets a squiggly underline). The code still runs and executes just fine. What do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: normally it's enough to have react.js (debug version, non-minified) included in project (note: it should be available locally in project directory)

Answer (score 1):

Add the react-DefinitelyTyped library to you JavaScript Libraries in WebStorm's preferences. Use the Download... button to search for it and then download it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put your cursor over where you are getting the src and hit alt-enter.  Webstorm will download it for you.